# I Have A Random Colour Program And I Need It To Rapidly Switch Through Colours

Tags: java

I have an ActionListener for my 'Aneurysm Mode' Button but when I press it, it does nothing...

Here is the code for the ActionListener:

```
private class AneurysmMode implements ActionListener {


           AneurysmMode () {}

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                while (true) {

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(colours[(int)(Math.random()*(9)+0)]);  
                    }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                }   
            }
        }           
    }
```

Comment: That `try..catch` is suppressing any useful warning or error you might get.

Comment: Put a print statement in that InterruptedException, see what happens. :)

Comment: How do you run this code? Is `AneurysmMode` intended to be a button?

Comment: @ItamarGreen Aneurysm Mode is a Button. Here is my full code http://hastebin.com/uxapunowis.java

Comment: @ItamarGreen The [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) interface can be invoked by any class that implements the interface, so a button would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Unless you are making something sophisticated such as a game where you need much control over all the rendering. If not, you can make full use of `javax.swing.timer` instead of implementing your own rendering loop.

You should not apply the rendering loop or sleep in the EDT. The actions within `actionPerformed` is usually a "one-time" action.

Your actionPerformed in the button in this case works just like an "on/off" button, hence all you need to do is to turn on/off the timer (which controls the animation) when it is clicked:

```
class DrawingSpace extends JPanel{

    private JButton button;
    private Timer timer;
    private int idx;
    private Color[] colors;    

    public DrawingSpace(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        initComponents();
        add(button);    
    }

    public void initComponents(){
        idx = 0;
        colors = new Color[]{Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN};
        button = new JButton("Let the colors rock!");
        timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener(){  
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                //Change color every (approx) 100 milliseconds
                idx = (idx + 1) % colors.length;   //cycle through the colours
                setBackground(colors[idx]);
            }               
        });    

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(!timer.isRunning())
                    timer.start();
                else
                    timer.stop();   
            }   
        }); 
    }
}
```

A runner class to run the code:

```
class RainbowRunner{
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        // Run the GUI code on the EDT
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {     
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rainbow Frame");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new DrawingSpace());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);             
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the variable idx do?

Comment: You use that to indicate which color's turn to cycle.

Comment: Cant you just use random?

Comment: Of course, it is your choice. This is only an example.

Answer (score 4):

You're sleeping the event dispatch thread, that's a bad idea. You will be adding the new colour to the event queue, but never actioning it because your button action listener doesn't return. If you take the while loop out of the button handler it should change every time the button is pressed.

A better option would be to change the colour in a timer action event and start the timer with a button press.

Comment: How would I do it with a timer?

Comment: Have a timer object, with an action listener that sets the background colour. The action listener of your button should then start the timer. Have a look at the documentation for java.swing.timer I think there's a fairly verbose tutorial there.

Comment: This is what I have so far but it doesn't do anything when i press it...


`Timer time = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     
     while (true) {
     
     time.start();
      
   frame.getContentPane().setBackground(colours[(int)(Math.random()*(9)+0)]);
    
    }
    }
   });`

Comment: You don't need the `while(true)`, just let the timer change it every time it's action listener is fired.

Comment: I removed it but it still does nothing. How can I fix it?

Comment: actionPerformed is called by the event dispatch thread, that's the thread in charge of keeping the ui up to date and handling buttons and other events. Pausing it is a bad idea as it will stop your UI responding. You should never need to, there are always alternative ways.

Comment: What is the other way?

Comment: Are you starting the timer in your button action listener? You look to be starting it in the action listener you've added to the timer, that's not needed.

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to start when the button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

You would not want to throw the entire game loop (or whatever you call it) into your `actionPerformed` method. What you can do is, on every button click, trigger the timer if it is not started:

```
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(!timer.isRunning())
                timer.start();
            else
                timer.stop();   
        }   
    });
```

You may consider using a `javax.swing.timer` instead of writing your own loop.

In your `javax.swing.timer`, you can have something like this:

```
    timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener(){  
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //Change color every (approx) 100 milliseconds
            idx = (idx + 1) % colours.length;   //cycle through the colours
            frame.setBackground(colours[idx]);
        }               
    });
```

Comment: Would you mind adding that to a hastebin with my code and showing where to implement it?

Comment: @Herseept72 Take a look at my solution below.

Comment: @Herseept72 If my solution helps. you may accept ***one*** solution here which helped you most by clicking the hollow looking tick beside that solution. You get 2 rep points in return.